# I developed an application with nodejs, using ts and express, but there is no output when using tsc packaging

Tags: javascript

I executed tsc and hoped it could be packaged in the dist directory, but nothing happened after execution.

Execute nodemon and the program runs normally.

The following is the main information, please check

Contains package.json, tsconfgi, and basic file directories

I developed an application with nodejs, using ts and express, but there is no output when using tsc packaging.

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon",
    "start": "node dist/app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/app.ts",
    "prebuild": "tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json --fix",
    "build": "tsc",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "build3": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "depend": "cmd.exe /c 'npx dependency-cruiser --format json > dependencies.json'"
  },
  "author": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.8",
    "@babel/node": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-loader": "8.2.4",
    "eslint": "^8.13.0",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "iconv-lite": "^0.6.3",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "node-tesr": "0.0.9",
    "puppeteer": "^13.7.0",
    "sqlite3": "^5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.17.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.16.11",
    "@ffprobe-installer/ffprobe": "^1.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.10",
    "cross-env": "7.0.3",
    "dependency-cruiser": "^12.10.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.1",
    "file-loader": "6.2.0",
    "get-video-duration": "^4.0.0",
    "log4js": "^6.4.6",
    "node-ffprobe": "^3.0.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "tesseract.js": "^2.1.5",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.2",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack": "^5.76.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist", 
    "rootDir": ".",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": { 
      "@src/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ],
       "@base/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
    },
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": false, 
    "sourceMap": true, 
    "skipLibCheck": true, 
    "allowJs": true, 
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, 
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": false, 
    "noImplicitAny": false, 
    "noEmit": true, 
    "experimentalDecorators": true, 
    "noUnusedLocals": false, 
    "noUnusedParameters": false, 
    "noImplicitReturns": false, 
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": true, 
  },
  
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
  ],
}
```

```
Project Directory


-server(root)
  --src
    ---pages
      ----common
    app.ts
  --dist
  --package.json
  --tsconfig.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this you can change "noEmit": true to "noEmit": false.
Modified code sample:

```
   {
 "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5",
   "module": "commonjs",
   "outDir": "dist", 
   "rootDir": ".",
   "baseUrl": ".",
   "paths": { 
     "@src/*": [
       "./src/*"
     ],
      "@base/*": [
       "./*"
     ],
   },
   "lib": [
     "es6",
     "DOM"
   ],
   "moduleResolution": "node",
   "strict": false, 
   "sourceMap": true, 
   "skipLibCheck": true, 
   "allowJs": true, 
   "resolveJsonModule": true,
   "esModuleInterop": true, 
   "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, 
   "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
   "isolatedModules": false, 
   "noImplicitAny": false, 
   "noEmit": false, 
   "experimentalDecorators": true, 
   "noUnusedLocals": false, 
   "noUnusedParameters": false, 
   "noImplicitReturns": false, 
   "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
   "noImplicitUseStrict": true, 
 },

 "include": [
   "src/**/*"
 ],
 "exclude": [
   "node_modules",
 ],
```

}

Comment: My God, I'm stupid. This problem has troubled me for several days. Thank you so much

Comment: These problems occur ;)